# underbrace text not on the same vertical line

Tags: align

How do I fix the code such that the underbrace text "xxxx" are all on the same line?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\hat{y}_{\Psi}^t &= \Psi(g^t_\text{h}) \\
\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,i} &= \Phi([y^t \circ m,x_i^t,\mathrm{BPS}_i,s])\\
\hat{y}^t &= \underbrace{y^t \circ m_s}_\text{xxxx} + \underbrace{\textstyle\sum_i (\hat{\alpha}_i^t \hat{y}^t_{\Phi,i}}_\text{xxxx} + \underbrace{\hat{\alpha}^t_{\text{h}}\hat{y}_{\Psi}^t)}_{\mathclap{\text{xxxx}}} \circ (1 - m_s)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. I've already suggested a command `\tsum` instead of the wrong `\textstyle\sum`.
2. I also suggested you to use `\mathrm{h}` and *not* `\text{h}`, because you'd get an italic “h” in case the font active outside math mode is italic.
3. `_\text{whatever}` is wrong and should be `_{\text{whatever}}`, the same for `\mathrm`.

Finally, you should test your code before posting: with the posted code you get an error because `\mathclap` is undefined (it requires `mathtools`); on the other hand, in the particular case `\mathclap` isn't needed.

Today's suggestion is to define a replacement for `\underbrace`: compare my output with yours, particularly for the spacing around the last `\circ`.

Now the solution: identify the deeper item to be underbraced in the formula and use a vertical phantom. I suggest to use a local command to ease input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tsum}{\mathop{\textstyle\sum}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\ubrace}[2]{{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\hat{y}_{\Psi}^t &= \Psi(g^t_{\mathrm{h}}) \\
\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,i} &= \Phi([y^t \circ m,x_i^t,\mathrm{BPS}_i,s])\\
\hat{y}^t &=
  \newcommand{\?}{\vphantom{\hat{\alpha}_i^t \hat{y}^t_{\Phi,i}}}%
  \ubrace{\? y^t \circ m_s}{\text{xxxx}} +
  \ubrace{\tsum_i (\hat{\alpha}_i^t \hat{y}^t_{\Phi,i}}{\text{xxxx}} +
  \ubrace{\? \hat{\alpha}^t_{\mathrm{h}}\hat{y}_{\Psi}^t)}{\text{xxxx}} \circ (1 - m_s)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As an alternative for fixing `\underbrace` you should use

```
{\underbrace{<formula>}_{<subscript>}}
```

with an additional pair of braces (which is essentially what `\ubrace` does).

A similar fix should be used for `\overbrace`.

Comment: thank you so very much

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to (a) define a typographic strut -- an invisible object with a certain height above and depth below the baseline -- whose depth is given by the material in the middle `\underbrace` term, and (b) add this strut to the first and third `\underbrace` terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% define a typographic strut:
\newcommand\mystrut{\vphantom{\textstyle\sum_i\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,i}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\hat{y}_{\Psi}^t 
    & = \Psi(g^t_\mathrm{h})\\
\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,i} 
    & = \Phi([y^t \circ m,x_i^t,\mathrm{BPS}_i,s])  \\
\hat{y}^t 
    & = \underbrace{y^t \circ m_s \mystrut}_{\text{xxxx}}
      + \underbrace{\textstyle\sum_i (\hat{\alpha}_i^t \hat{y}^t_{\Phi,i})}_{\text{xxxx}}
      + \underbrace{\hat{\alpha}^t_{\mathrm{h}}\hat{y}_{\Psi}^t \mystrut}_{\text{xxxx}} \circ (1 - m_s)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico, I try this, but result wasn't as I expected, I will test again asap.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much for editing my answer.